# R - help on basic one-way permutation test

Tags: r, permutation

I am having difficulty coding a one-way permutation test. I have data from a running race, and I'm looking at two columns to see if runners from abroad or the US are faster. The left column is two factors, A or D - abroad or domestic (abroad runners are CLEARLY much faster). The right column is their times, in minutes. Because the abroad sample size is so small, I want to do a permutation test that answers the question: if the times were randomly assigned, what is the probability that the Abroad runners were assigned the fast times?

I would appreciate any guidance. The only code I have is turning the column into factors. I also have an attempt at a permutation test but I don't know where it's going.

```
abroaddomestic$City.f <- factor(abroaddomestic$City, labels = c("Abroad", "Domestic"))
msamp <- mean(abroad$TimeInMin) 
mpop <- mean(abroaddomestic$TimeInMin) 
msim <- replicate(10000, mean(sample(abroaddomestic$TimeInMin, 250))) 
sum(abs(msim-mpop) >= abs(msamp-mpop))/10000
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Carl Witthoft's answer, you could think about the simulation as coming from a binomial distribution. I.e., simulate if each runner's domestic or abroad type were a random draw.

From there, you can treat the number of runners in the top ten (or whatever threshold) as your statistic and test that against a simulated distribution where domestic/abroad type is assigned randomly to all runners. For example, assume 1000 runners, with 100 from abroad:

```
# calculate your test statistic
# as the number of abroad runners in top ten
statistic <- 3
# 5000 simulations of number of abroad in top ten times
# take number of values greater than statistic as p-value
sum(replicate(5000,sum(rbinom(1000,1,.1)[1:10])) > statistic)/5000
# or, equivalently:
sum(replicate(5000,rbinom(1,10,.1)) > statistic)/5000
```

In this example, your p-value is something like 0.01, thus rejecting the null hypothesis that placement in the top ten is randomly (independent of domestic/abroad type).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to bother with factors, or pretty much any of your source data. Say, e.g., you have 1000 runners of which 10 are 'abroad' . Then all you need to do is calculate(simulate) the probability of the first 10 values of `runif(1000)` being in the top X% of all random values generated.  The order of generation is irrelevant since you're assuming noncorrelation.